How do I remove this line from the render in the compositor?
I am using the compositor to draw an outline around objects, but I want to be able to remove a specific part from the outline.



What I want is to be able to remove the outline that appears at the intersection. I can isolate it using cryptomattes but from there I have been unable to remove it from the render. I have mainly tried the mix/math node and trying to convert the image into an alpha mask but it never got the what I needed exactly.


Use the separated line as a factor to "mix color" between the original image and the new image. Maybe use a color ramp with constants to clearly separate values before the mix.
